# What is the concept display pdf file with page wise in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am doing a simple program. I have 3 pdf file for 1 chapter like "pdf_chapter_1_page_1.pdf","pdf_chapter_1_page_2.pdf","pdf_chapter_1_page_3.pdf". In first chapter we have 3 pdf file. I want to display these 3 pdf file in iPhone. When user will open application he will be on 1st page of chapter and whenever he will drag either horizontal or vertical next pages of same chapter will be loaded.

What is the concept to do it ? Code reference will be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. [UIPageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is one way.

Comment: Please tell me another way also. i am trying of this way.

Answer (score 0):

**You can show pdf page in iphone using UIWebView. It will show you in  pagewise.**

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];  
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];  
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];  
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];  
[webView loadRequest:request];  
[self.view addSubview:webView];  
[webView release];
```

Comment: you did not get. I dont have one pdf file. I have 3 pdf file for each page show. Above code is for showing for one pdf file.